# Switching gcc version on remote Linux based HPC (no root rights)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

There is a specific program i need to run using c++11 libraries offered by gcc-4.8 and higher. The remote HPC on which i am trying to run the program has gcc-4.6.1. I was able to install the gcc-4.8.2 version on the HPC in a user specified directory, say
/share/user/gccInstall

(gccInstall has the /bin and /lib (etc) folders you get after installation)
I need to switch to this version for compiling my program. I tried using update-alternatives --config gcc, but it does not return anything. 
Can anyone help me solve this!

**EDIT**:
Was able to change the gcc version using the following commands:
setenv PATH /share/user/gccInstall/bin
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/user/gccInstall/lib

Now gcc --version returns 4.8.2.
But encountered another error while compiling: 
g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
what am i missing?

Many Thanks.

Comment: I am not confident enough to post this as an answer, but you can try this: Set `CC` and `CXX` while configuring, e.g. `CC=/path/to/gcc CXX=/path/to/g++ cmake .`. Then prepend `/path/to/newlibs` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when running the compiled program.

Comment: @BaummitAugen be confident. Potentially also prepend `PATH` to make the command line `gcc` command pick up the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different version of g++ that you want to use then make sure you're getting the right one according to your `$PATH` or else specify the full path to the g++ you want.  The other thing to be aware of is that you will probably need to update the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to get the necessary libraries from your new gcc installation.

What exactly is the problem you're having?  Can you compile but not run?  Does compilation fail?  Do you have any error messages you can share?

Comment: i am able to change the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH by the command:   setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /share/user/gccInstall/lib.   which gcc returns the path to the older version which means the system does not recognize the new gcc installation. For that i guess i need to make changes to the $PATH variable. What should the path be?

Comment: Compiling with the command: g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
gives the following error: 
 /share/user/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.3.0/platforms/linux64/gcc-4.6.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is after using the following lines in Makefile:

CC = /share/user/gccInstall/bin/gcc
CXX = /share/user/gccInstall/bin/g++

Comment: If you use the command `ldd /share/user/gccInstall/bin/g++` then what does it say for the libmpc.so.2 library?  We want to set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it loads the gcc-4.8.2 version instead of the 4.6.1 one.

Comment: This is the response i got from the command. Not sure what it means though
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003068200000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003067a00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003066a00000)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as you say that your new GCC installation is
under `/share/user/gccInstall` then if you add the option

```
-B/share/user/gccInstall
```

to each invocation of `g++` or `gcc` then it will have this
effect:

> -Bprefix
>      This option specifies where to find the executables, libraries, include files, and data files of the compiler itself.

(from [Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options))

This should help, and will perhaps be enough.